# Use multiple dictionaries or a single huge one

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

I have a general question about dictionaries in C#.
Say I read in a text file, split it up into keys and values and store them in a dictionary.
Would it be more useful to put them all into a single dictionary or split it up into smaller ones?
It probably wouldn't make a huge difference with small text files but some of them have more than 100.000 lines.
What would you recommend?

Comment: I agree with Eric...do it simple and easy first, then optimize/fix as necessary if that doesn't meet your goals. That said, a .NET generic Dictionary can easily handle 100,000 elements, so I'd anticipate no trouble in your stated worst-case scenario.

Comment: If you are on .NET framework less than 4.5 - then note about 2Gb memory limitation to any single object. I.e. your "huge" dictionary can't exceed 2 Gb in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First rule is always to benchmark before trying optimization. That being said, some people might have done the benchmarking for you. Check those [results here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919000250/http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-size)

From the article (Just in case it disappears from the net)

> The smaller Dictionary (with half the number of keys) was much faster.
> In this case, the behavior of both Dictionaries on the input was
> identical. This means that having unneeded keys in the Dictionary
> makes it slower.
>
> My perspective is that you should use separate Dictionaries for
> separate purposes. If you have two sets of keys, do not store them in
> the same Dictionary. If you can divide them up, you can enhance lookup
> performance.
>
> Credit: dotnetperls.com

Also from the article :

> Full Dictionary:      791 ms
> Half-size Dictionary: 591 ms [faster]

Maybe you can live with much less code and 200ms more, it really depends on your application

Comment: I can confirm this, on 1 dictionary with 2.6 million keys it was running almost a second per lookup, splitting it into just shy of 100 dictionaries put me at around half a second.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the original article is either inaccurate or outdated. In any case, the statements regarding "dictionary size" have since been removed. Now, to answer the question:

Targeting `.NET 6 x64` gives **BETTER performance for a SINGLE dictionary**. In fact, performance gets worse the more dictionaries you use:

```
|        Method |      Mean |    Error |    StdDev |    Median |
|-------------- |----------:|---------:|----------:|----------:|
|  Dictionary_1 |  91.54 us | 1.815 us |  3.318 us |  89.88 us |
|  Dictionary_2 | 122.55 us | 1.067 us |  0.998 us | 122.19 us |
| Dictionary_10 | 390.77 us | 7.757 us | 18.882 us | 382.55 us |
```

The results should come as no surprise. For N-dictionary lookup you will calculate the hash code *up to N times* for every item to look up, instead of doing it just once. Also, you have to loop through the list of dictionaries which introduces a miniscule performance hit. All in all, it just makes sense.

Now, under some bizarre conditions, it might be possible to gain some speed using N-dictionary. E.g. Consider a tiny CPU cache, thrashing, hash code collisions etc. Have yet to encounter such a scenario though...

**Benchmark code**

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace MyBenchmarks;

public class DictionaryBenchmark
{
    private const int N = 1000000;
    private readonly string[] data;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> dictionary;
    private readonly List<Dictionary<string, string>> dictionaries2;
    private readonly List<Dictionary<string, string>> dictionaries10;

    public DictionaryBenchmark()
    {
        data = Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(n => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToArray();
        
        dictionary = data.ToDictionary(x => x);
        dictionaries2 = CreateDictionaries(2);
        dictionaries10 = CreateDictionaries(10);
    }

    private List<Dictionary<string, string>> CreateDictionaries(int count)
    {
        int chunkSize = N / count;
        return data.Select((item, index) => (Item: item, Index: index))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
            .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Item).ToDictionary(x => x))
            .ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Dictionary_1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1000)
        {
            dictionary.ContainsKey(data[i]);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Dictionary_2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1000)
        {
            foreach (var d in dictionaries2)
            {
                if (d.ContainsKey(data[i]))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }            
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Dictionary_10()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1000)
        {
            foreach (var d in dictionaries10)
            {
                if (d.ContainsKey(data[i]))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() => BenchmarkRunner.Run<DictionaryBenchmark>();
}
```